# Using if_else, I can't return the column used as the conditional if the conditional is false

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I've created a `flag` variable of different job descriptions in a dataset.  I would like to change the each `flag==true` into the same row position from another variable.

I've tried `ifelse` and `if_else;` but all I've been able to get is a list of the changed values for the `true` conditional and `NA`s.

Here is a reproducible example using `diamonds`:

```
mydata <- diamonds[1:10,c(3,4)] 
mydata$position <- c('flag','cathy')
mydata
mydata$new.vary <- mydata %>% if_else(color=='E',position,color)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be mixing `dplyr` and `base` R frameworks.

In `base` R, you would use

```
mydata$new.vary <- ifelse(mydata$color == 'E', mydata$position, mydata$color)
```

This works, but you should take note that `mydata$position` is a character object, and `mydata$color` is a factor, which is represented internally as an integer.  If you try to run the same code with `if_else` from the `dplyr` package, you'll get the following:

```
mydata$new.vary <- if_else(mydata$color == 'E', mydata$position, mydata$color)
Error: `false` must be type character, not integer
```

`if_else` is a little more strict than `ifelse`, requiring that both the `true` and `false` arguments have the same type.

If you want to use the `dplyr` approach, you can use

```
mydata %>% 
  mutate(new.vary = ifelse(color == 'E', position, color))
```

or, if you want to use `dplyr`'s `if_else`, try

```
mydata %>% 
  mutate(color = as.character(color),
         new.vary = if_else(color == 'E', position, color))
```